Expected number of rolls to get a 1 given that game ends if you get a 1 or 2.

Question: Suppose you play a game where you continually roll a die
until you obtain either a 1 or a 2. If you receive a 1, then you cash
out the sum of all of your previous rolls (excluding the 1). If you
receive a 2, then you receive nothing. You do not have the decision to
cash out mid-game. What is your expected payout?

I have tried to use conditional expectation but for some reason I am not getting the right answer. Here is my method -

Let X be the payout, A be the event that 1 comes before 2 and B be the event that 2 comes before 1. $E(X) = E(X|A)P(A) + E(X|B)P(B)$.
$E(X|B) = 0$ because if we get a 2 before 1, then we get 0. Also $P(A) = P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry since it is equally likely to get a 2 before 1 or 1 before 2.
So we are left with $E(X) = \frac{E(X|A)}{2}$.
$E(X|A)$ is the expected payout given we get 1 before 2. That means expected number of rolls until we get a 1 (not including the roll where we get a 1) * expected sum of those rolls. We know each roll has an expected value of 2.5.
So we just need to work out the expected number of rolls until we get a 1 GIVEN that we get 1 before 2. Let's denote it by $E$ Here is where the problem is but i am not sure why.
$E = \frac{1}{6} * 1 + \frac{4}{6} * (1 + E)$. The first term on the RHS is if you get a 1 straight away. The second term on the RHS is if you don't get a 1, you must get 3,4,5 or 6 as you can't get a 2. You are back to the beginning so it is $1 + E$.
Solving this I get $E = 2.5$, but apparently the answer should be $E = 3$ which then affects the overall answer to this question.

Any help with why this is wrong would be much appreciated.

You switched from "getting a 1 to end the game" to "getting a 5 to end the game", if I understand your approach correctly. If not, can you explain your reasoning why you want to get a 5?

sorry it was a typo. don't know what happened. It should be 1 or 2 ends the game but if you get 1, you get the sum of all your previous rolls and if you get 2, you get nothing. I have corrected it now

Your question and your attempted answer quote different stopping condition.

i've fixed it now thanks for letting me know

The question in the header does not match the question in the body.  The question in the header doesn't really make sense, as half the games end without ever seeing a $1$.

The problem with your approach in determining the expected number of throws needed to reach $1$, assuming that $1$ occurs before $2$, is that you failed to discard the option $2$. You state that:
$$E(X) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot 1 + \frac{4}{6} \cdot (1 + E(X))$$
However, since you removed $2$ from your sample space ("if I throw a $2$, it just ignore it and continue rolling without counting the throw"), you should have:
$$E(X) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{6} E(X) + \frac{4}{6} \cdot (1 + E(X)) \iff \frac{1}{6} E(X) = \frac{5}{6} \iff E(X) = 5$$
Thus, if you cannot throw a $2$, the expected number of throws to reach $1$ equals $5$. This makes sense, because if the probability of a stopping event happening equals $p = \frac{1}{5}$, the expected number of attempts to reach this event equals $\frac{1}{p} = 5$. However, this is not what you are after: if either a $1$ or a $2$ is thrown, the game immediately ends.
In this particular case, we find that the expected number of throws needed to get $1$ or a $2$ equals $\frac{1}{\frac{2}{6}} = 3$. Since the last throw should be discarded, the expected number of dice throws that count toward the potential reward equals $2$.
The expected value of both throws equals $\frac{3 + 4 + 5 + 6}{4} = \frac{9}{2}$, since the possibility of throwing $1$ or $2$ should be discarded. Furthermore, since these throws are independent of one another, the expected value of the potential reward equals $2 \cdot \frac{9}{2} = 9$.
Since you only get the reward half of the time (the instance in which you end the sequence with $1$), the expected value of the reward equals:
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 9 = \frac{9}{2}$$
This is confirmed by the following Python code, which simulates a large number of sequences:
from random import randint


reward_tot = 0
n_iterations = 100000
for i in range(n_iterations):
    reward = 0
    d = randint(1, 6)
    while d > 2:
        reward += d
        d = randint(1, 6)
    if d == 1:
        reward_tot += reward
reward_avg = reward_tot / n_iterations
print(reward_avg)

You will observe that the outcome consistently resembles $4.5$.

Thank you for this answer - I understand your method as to how you got 3 rolls as being the expected number of rolls to get a 1 or 2, but do you know what i am doing wrong in my approach though? I am trying to directly calculate the expected number of rolls of getting a 1 before a 2 but I end up with 5/2 instead of 3

@Apex345, I updated my answer to try and explain your mistake.

Thank you for your updated answer. I kind of get it - so because I have said that 1 comes before 2, 2 isn't allowed to be in the sample space so we have 5 options to choose from, not 6, which gives $E(X) = 5$. I also get that $E(X)$ isn't what we want as this just tells us the number of rolls to get to a 1 given that 1 comes before 2, but doesnt take into account the fact that getting a 2 can also end the game. But what I don't get is my method seems mathematically fine, but produces the wrong answer

I don't get why doing: 'work out the number of rolls for the game to end and divide by 2 for the case where 1 comes before 2' is mathematically different to 'divide into 2 cases - when 1 comes before 2 and when 2 comes before 1 and then work out the number of rolls to get to 1 comes before 2'
